# Sort by timestamp on has_many after scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sorting, activerecord

I have a User object, a Package object (`User has_many packages`) and then a `LocationTracker` (`User has_many location_trackers`), which acts as a join table between User and Package, but just tracks details such as the most recent package delivery.

I'd like to sort my Users based on the most recent package they sent. The LocationTracker has an attribute `last_received_from_user`

I can easily sort the users from a certain location by ordering by the `last_received_from_user` attribute, however I'd also like to have a global index page that shows all of the Users, sorted by the last package they delivered.

I'm having trouble grouping the users. I'm attempting to use a `DISTINCT ON(last_received_from_user)`, but then it complains that the attribute isn't in the `group`, and when I add it to the `group`, it `groups` by that timestamp, which is obviously pretty unique, so I get duplicate users showing up.

My current code is as follows:

```
User.includes(:location_trackers)
  .group("location_trackers.user_id, users.id")
  .order("location_trackers.last_received_from_user #{order} NULLS LAST")
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I've got the `last_received_from_user` which allows me to sort users from a SINGLE location well. However, I need to be able to scope based on what could be a number of different options. For example, only show users in a certain area (Which could be compromised of a few locations), or order by ALL users for ALL locations. The attribute works great for a single user-location relationship, but fails when it comes to attempting to perform the search on more than 1 location.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to sort my Users based on the most recent package they sent

Wouldn't it be easier (and way more efficient) having an attribute like `latest_delivery_location` and using a callback on the User model like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_update :update_latest_delivery_location

  private

  def update_latest_delivery_location
    update_attributes(
      latest_delivery_location: location_trackers.last.last_received_from_user
    )
  end
end
```

Or updating such attribute after an order has been placed / dispatched. I'd go for this approach because is easier to maintain and, if you want it more performing you could always add an index on `users.latest_delivery_location` for sorting operations.

Comment: EDIT: Misread your answer slightly. Yes, that would work, but again only allows for a single case, but this needs to be a dynamic scope that can applied. I used the global example as just an example. Edited the post for further elaboration.